# How was the Swing GUI toolkit created?

Tags: java, swing

I'm asking this question out of curiosity, and also it seems like the knowledge I will gain from it will be beneficial.

How was the `javax.swing.*` import created? Wikipedia tells me

> They are written entirely in Java

So I'd be very interested to actually see the code that was used to create the tools.

Comment: Download JDK and  import the package `import javax.swing.*`

Comment: You can just read the source code: http://openjdk.java.net/groups/swing/.

Comment: You can also contrast them with the [RCP](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Rich_Client_Platform) from eclipse, and the earlier [AWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

link to download the JDK. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

The source for all the classes comes as part of the JDK.  So if you "are very interested to actually see the code" just download a JDK.

Some of it is very interesting, but it is all things you could create on your own given enough time.